# Text shadow not behind gradient clip background

Tags: css, webkit

I am trying to get a logo to use gradient fill with clip and then place a text shadow behind it. However the shadow always seems to be placed on top?

Obviously I can do this in SVG etc. but for other reasons I would like do it with CSS.

I have created a fiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/Mgz6H/

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have created a fiddle could you tell us where it is? You'll also need to add some of your code to your question.

Comment: Noob alert, sorry, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Mgz6H/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used z-index for depth and created absolute div element for shadow.
Please check the updated code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mgz6H/2)

**CSS**

```
.logo-shadow {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    text-shadow:3px 3px 3px black;
    color:transparent;
    z-index:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">
        <span>Light</span>
        <span id="swap">Meter</span>
        <span id="me">.com</span>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-shadow">
        <span>Light</span>
        <span id="swap">Meter</span>
        <span id="me">.com</span>
    </div>
</div>​
```